# is it possible to pass 2 parameters to listfieldcallback class?

Tags: blackberry

i am new to blackberry development. i want to know is there any other way to solve my application. i have developed a simple calculator application which displays like,

```
value1 : 6
value2 : 3
Calculate

+  :  9
-  :  3
*  :  18
/  :  2
```

where value1 and value2 are two edit fields, calculate is ButonField. And in my code i had written a String array {"+","-","*","/"} which is used to pass to the class implementing ListFieldCallBack.

it is coded like

```
for(int i = 0; i<array.length;i++)
        {
            mylist.insert(i);
                    //calculated the result 
            myCallBack.insert(array[i]+"#"+result );
        }
```

and in my drawListRow i had seperated the array value and result. and shows in two drawtexts.

it is working well. now my question is that is there any other way which i can pass both the value in array and the calculated result? now i am passing the array value and result as a string and splitting it there to display my result. but if it is possible to pass arguments seperatly, i dont need to use the splitter function there. so what is the way? or is there any other way? plz suggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this is not related to blackberry. This is related to idioms we use in OOP delelopment.

Since your list item represent 2 pieces of info - a math operation and a result - you need to create a model for the list item that encapsulates those 2 pieces of info:

```
public class ListItem {

    public final String operation;
    public final String result;

    public ListItem(String operation, String result) {
        this.operation = operation;
        this.result    = result;
    }
}
```

Then inside of the `ListFieldCallBack` you should have a `Vector` of `ListItem` instances. So when you call `myCallBack.insert(new ListItem(operation, result));` it adds the list item to the vector.

When your are in `drawListRow(ListField listField, Graphics graphics, int index, int y, int width)`, you first get the list item by its index, then you can easily get the list item state without the need of splitting a string or doing any other dirty actions. So the code becomes clean and OOP-ish:

```
ListItem li = // get ListItem by index

li.operation; // operation
li.result;    // result
```

Comment: @Arhimed:- thank you Arhimed. Actually i had tried that. but in that insert function on ListFieldCallBack, i had done mistake. Ur guidance really helped me. thank alot